# getting output using pysnmp

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

Forgive me if this is such a simple thing but I am new to Python, pysnmp and SNMP.

I am trying to run some very simple queries using SNMP to get configuration information from a device and for some reason following the documentation [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/pysnmp-hlapi-tutorial.html#making-snmp-query).

I am not getting any output even though I can walk the SNMP via snmpwalk and googling seems to just show the example I have below.

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

from pysnmp.hlapi import *

varCommunity = "public"
varServer = "demo.snmplabs.com"
varPort = 161

g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData(varCommunity),
       UdpTransportTarget((varServer, varPort)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0)))

next(g)
```

If I add

```
print(g)
```

I would get the following output

```
<generator object getCmd at 0x7f25964847d8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
next(g)
```

Will return the next value from the generator. If you were typing this code in the Python console, you'd see the actual result. However, since you're running this from a file, the result will just be discarded.

You need to put the `print` around it. E.g.

```
print(next(g))
```

For easier debugging, you could get the list of all results like this:

```
print(list(g))
```

Comment: Is there a way to return just the value?
e.g. return the value "demo.snmplabs.com"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I have no experience with `pysnmp` or SNMP in general. Using `next(g)` is what I'd say by guessing. Network protocols are asynchronous by nature, that's why the library returns a generator instead of simply a value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your original script with a few changes and comments that hopefully would get you up to speed with pysnmp:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

varCommunity = "public"
varServer = "demo.snmplabs.com"
varPort = 161

g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData(varCommunity),
           UdpTransportTarget((varServer, varPort)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0)))

# this is what you get from SNMP agent
error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds = next(g)

if not error_indication and not error_status:
    # each element in this list matches a sequence of `ObjectType`
    # in your request.
    # In the code above you requested just a single `ObjectType`,
    # thus we are taking just the first element from response
    oid, value = var_binds[0]
    print(oid, '=', value)
```

You may found [pysnmp documentation](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/pysnmp-hlapi-tutorial.html#making-snmp-query) insightful as well. ;-)